# How can I find the url of the current Action in an Area from a ChildAction in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to workout the url for the current route from the context of a child action in asp.net mvc.

To do this I am using:

```
Url.RouteUrl(ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values)
```

This is fine, expect it doesn't take into account areas. How can this be extended to take into account the current areas routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did in the end. Essentially I check if the current action has an area and then add this to the dictionary that I pass to the `RouteUrl` call.

```
var context = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext;

var routeValueDict = new RouteValueDictionary();

foreach (var value in context.RouteData.Values)
{
    routeValueDict.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
}

var area = context.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
if (area != null)
{
    routeValueDict.Add("area", area);
}

var url = Url.RouteUrl(routeValueDict);
return url;
```